# Заменить gzip-заголовок сжатого файла на zlib-заголовок

Tags: сжатие, gzip

Я знаю, что могу воспользоваться PHP

```
gzcompress($contents, 9);
```

(или использовать какой-то компрессор), но мне не нравится, что файл жмется не так эффективно, как это делает тот же 7zip(в режиме deflate, конечно же).

Так что как заменить gzip-заголовки на zlib-заголовки (с контрольной суммой ADLER32 и прочим)?

Comment: вы же понимаете, что смена заголовка на компрессию не влияет?

Comment: Конечно, понимаю :) Но мне все-равно очень нужно

Comment: Открываете файл, пишете новый заголовок, закрываете файл. Это если его длина в точности равна длине старого заголовка.